# Invalid predecessor when editing task in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I keep getting an error when trying to edit a task on snowflake: whenever I want to edit the task I keep getting the following error message:

> SQL-Fehler [91085] [42601]: Invalid predecessor
>   TableNameA_001_update_newdata was specified.

The task itself looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK "TableNameA_001_update_newdata"
WAREHOUSE = marketing_wh 
AFTER "TableNameA_001_delete" AS
INSERT INTO tableA
...
```

By now I do not understand what is triggering the error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't use qualified `TASK` names (with database and schema in the `TASK` name).

If you inadvertedly change context (switch database or schema) the new context will not contain any task named "TableNameA_001_delete".

That will result in the error message `"Invalid predecessor <TASK name> was specified."`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! changed the name to be <database.schema.task> and I am receiving the same error message.

Comment: It is not "TableNameA_001_update_newdata" that will create the error, it is "TableNameA_001_delete".  Create _both_ with fully qualified names, and reference the predecessor fully qualified also.

Comment: You should change context to the schema where you create the tasks.  Then issue SHOW TASKS to make sure you got it right.

Comment: Also, both tasks need to have the same _owner_.  If you have some mysterious FUTURE GRANT i place, it might interfere with the ownership requirement.

Comment: checked all of it and the error kept popping up. I resolved the problem by splitting it apart into multiple tasks and now it is working. Don't really know why but it is working fine.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you, but your comment about "splitting it apart" tells me that the problem lied in the parts that you _did not include_ in your description, which makes it impossible for this forum to help...